# How to plot a large number of density plots with different categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a dataset in which I have one numeric variable and many categorical variables. I would like to make a grid of density plots, each showing the distribution of the numeric variable for different categorical variables, with the fill corresponding to subgroups of each categorical variable. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

dat <- flights %>%
  select(carrier, origin, distance) %>%
  mutate(origin = origin %>% as.factor,
         carrier = carrier %>% as.factor)

plot_1 <- dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = distance, fill = carrier)) +
  geom_density()

plot_1

plot_2 <- dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = distance, fill = origin)) +
  geom_density()

plot_2
```

I would like to find a way to quickly make these two plots. Right now, the only way I know how to do this is to create each plot individually, and then use grid_arrange to put them together. However, my real dataset has something like 15 categorical variables, so this would be very time intensive!

Is there a quicker and easier way to do this? I believe that the hardest part about this is that each plot has its own legend, so I'm not sure how to get around that stumbling block.

Comment: Please supply example data. I think you should convert 'width data' to 'long data' and then using `facet_wrap` to plot.

Comment: My post has a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solutions gives all the plots in a list. Here we make a single function that accepts a variable that you want to plot, and then use lapply with a vector of all the variables you want to plot.

```
fill_variables <- vars(carrier, origin)

func_plot <- function(fill_variable) {
  dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = distance, fill = !!fill_variable)) +
  geom_density()
}

plotlist <- lapply(fill_variables, func_plot)
```

If you have no idea of what those `!!` mean, I recommend watching [this 5 minute video that introduces the key concepts of tidy evaluation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nERXS3ssntw). This is what you want to use when you want to create this sorts of wrapper functions to do stuff programmatically. I hope this helps!

---

**Edit:** If you want to feed an array of strings instead of a quosure, you can change `!!fill_variable` for `!!sym(fill_variable)` as follows:

```
fill_variables <- c('carrier', 'origin')

func_plot <- function(fill_variable) {
  dat %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = distance, fill = !!sym(fill_variable))) +
    geom_density()
}

plotlist <- lapply(fill_variables, func_plot)
```

Comment: You are everything that is good in the world. Thanks so much! :)

Comment: One quick follow up. I'm having trouble passing the column names into 'fill_variables'. Right now I am extracting column names using the following code: 

flights_cat <- flights_subset %>%
  sapply(is.factor) %>%
  which()

flights_cat_names <- flights_subset %>%
  select(flights_cat) %>%
  colnames

Do you know how I can pass that vector of column names into 'vars'?

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution**

As @djc wrote in the comments, `I'm having trouble passing the column names into 'fill_variables'. Right now I am extracting column names using the following code...`

You can separate the categorical and numerical variables like; `cat_vars <- flights[, sapply(flights, is.character)]` for categorical variables and `cat_vars <- flights[, sapply(flights, !is.character)]` for continuous variables and then pass these vectors into the wrapper function given by `mgiormenti`

Full code is given below;

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

cat_vars <- flights[, sapply(flights, is.character)]
cont_vars<- flights[, !sapply(flights, is.character)]
dat <- flights %>%
  select(carrier, origin, distance) %>%
  mutate(origin = origin %>% as.factor,
         carrier = carrier %>% as.factor)

func_plot_cat <- function(cat_vars) {
  dat %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = distance, fill = !!cat_vars)) +
    geom_density()
}

func_plot_cont <- function(cont_vars) {
  dat %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = distance, fill = !!cont_vars)) +
    geom_point()
}

plotlist_cat_vars <- lapply(cat_vars, func_plot_cat)
plotlist_cont_vars<- lapply(cont_vars, func_plot_cont)
print(plotlist_cat_vars)
print(plotlist_cont_vars)
```